# How to move Azure SQL Database files to different location?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I want to move Azure SQL Database files (MDF, LDF, and TempDB) to a different disk location. Which TSQL command(s) can help?

Comment: Why do you need that? Azure SQL is a *managed* database. You don't have access to the server or the location of the files, nor should you need to. Do you have a performance problem that you assume is due to the placement of the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Azure SQL Database, you do not have the ability to move these files. If you want control over the filesystem, the best option is to use SQL Server in a VM.

Comment: Actually, I'd like to know *why* the OP wants to move the files. Is there a real problem that the OP assumes will be solved by moving the files?

Comment: One use case we came across if when our TempDB maxed out and we were hoping that we could change tempDB location to another dedicated drive